# Prove that the total number of parenthesizations of n matrices is Ω(4^n/n^3/2)

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, recurrence-relation, matrices, induction

Is it possible to prove the total number of parenthesizations of n matrices is Ω(4^n/n^3/2) ****using the Induction Method**?**

Recurrence formula from CLRS book

1. When n = 1, the sequence consists of just one matrix, and therefore there is only one way to fully parenthesize the matrix product.
2. When n ≥ 2, a fully parenthesized matrix product is the product of two fully parenthesized matrix subproducts, and the split between the two
   subproducts may occur between the kth and (k + 1)st matrices for any k = 1, 2, …, n − 1.
   $$P(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & \text{if }n = 1\\ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}P(k)P(n-k) & \text{if }n\geqslant 2.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: The sequence $P(n)$ is the sequence of [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). You should take a look.

Comment: Yes, this is the sequence of Catalan Numbers. I am particularly confused about what value to pick as a guess to prove using the Substitution method. Any idea on this?